# How to stop GroebnerBasis from automatically normalizing?

Tags: algebra, groebner-bases

I need to compute the Groebner basis modulus a set of prime without normalizing the Groebner basis output. Is this possible?

Example:

```
ideal = {8 x^2 y^2 + 5 x y^3 + 3 x^3 z + x^2 y z, 
   x^5 + 2 y^3 z^2 + 13 y^2 z^3 + 5 y z^4,
   8 x^3 + 12 y^3 + x z^2 + 3,
   7 x^2 y^4 + 18 x y^3 z^2 + y^3 z^3};
monos = {x, y, z};
GroebnerBasis[ideal,monos,Modulus->7]
```

I get:
{z^2, 2 + y^3, x}

But I need:
{z^2, 1 + 4 y^3, x}

Which is the Groebner basis of the original system since 7 is a lucky prime.

Comment: (1) Both are Groebner bases. (2) The one returned is what is called the "reduced" GB. (3) The last line of the input should be `GroebnerBasis[ideal, monos, Modulus -> 7]` (4) The fact that 7 is a lucky prime does not mean the GB mod 7 will equal the GB over Q (check definition of "lucky" in this context).

Comment: I am aware that 7 being lucky does not mean that the GB mod 7 will equal the GB over Q, and in this case it does. How do I stop GB from normalizing the first term?

Comment: There is no way to influence the algorithm in terms of avoiding the reduced form. There are ways of using the Chinese Remainder Algorithm to get a GB over Q after the fact (maybe you knew that). In this (somewhat uncommon) case only one prime would be needed. The key is then to find the right normalization. Short summary: it takes a bit of work.

Comment: I am using the Chinese Remainder Algorithm and multiple primes, but does the normalization not effect the result of the Chinese Remainder Algorithm?

Comment: Re CRA, my recollection is that one first "lifts" (via CRA) and then normalizes as a separate step (and in your example that first step is a no-op). But I confess I do not recall the details of that second step. I know I have coded it at least once in past, but I'd have to dig that up, or figure it out anew, to give anything more specific.

Comment: Okay, it's coming back. For normalizing one uses a simple extended GCD tactic. I'll try to write up a response later, once I have time to put together the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot change the way the polynomial coefficients are normalized in `GroebnerBasis`. To do recovery over Q when working with modulo-prime bases one can use Chinese remaindering. I will illustrate with this example. We'll use some different moduli.

```
ideal = {8 x^2 y^2 + 5 x y^3 + 3 x^3 z + x^2 y z, 
   x^5 + 2 y^3 z^2 + 13 y^2 z^3 + 5 y z^4, 8 x^3 + 12 y^3 + x z^2 + 3,
    7 x^2 y^4 + 18 x y^3 z^2 + y^3 z^3};
monos = {x, y, z};
gb7 = GroebnerBasis[ideal, monos, Modulus -> 7]
gb17 = GroebnerBasis[ideal, monos, Modulus -> 17]

(* Out[91]= {z^2, 2 + y^3, x}

Out[92]= {z^2, 13 + y^3, x} *)
```

This is an easy example of course. Only one polynomial might need any modification and that is the middle one. For that, if we normalize over Q so that the lead coefficient is 1, then only the trailing coefficient (the constant term) needs to be recovered. We see it is 2 mod 7, and 13 mod 17. CRA then tells us the value mod 7*17.

```
ChineseRemainder[{2, 13}, {7, 17}]

(* Out[93]= 30 *)
```

So now we need to find a rational corresponding to 30 mod 119 (=7*17). To do this we solve the extended gcd problem 119*x+30*y==gcd(119,30).

```
ExtendedGCD[7*17, 30]

(* Out[94]= {1, {-1, 4}} *)
```

The multipliers are (-1,4) so we see that 30*4 == 1 mod 119, or 30 = 1/4 modulo 119. This is, in a sense I will not define, the "smallest" rational equivalent to 30 mod 119. Our trailing coefficient is (possibly) 1/4 over the rationals, and the polynomial becomes `y^3+1/4` (or 4*y^3+1, on clearing denominators). One can get some confirmation by checking with one more mod-prime computation.

```
gb29 = GroebnerBasis[ideal, monos, Modulus -> 29]

(* Out[95]= {z^2, 22 + y^3, x} *)

ChineseRemainder[{2, 13, 22}, {7, 17, 29}]

(* Out[96]= 863 *)

ExtendedGCD[7*17*29, 863]

(* Out[97]= {1, {-1, 4}} *)
```

So it is also 1/4 mod 7*17*29=3451. This is not exactly proof that we have recovered the right coefficient but such stability after adding a new prime modulus does give good evidence for that. If one requires proof there are ways to go about that but that's outside the intended scope of this response.

I will remark that using mod 17 or mod 29 alone is sufficient in this example.

```
ExtendedGCD[17, 13]
ExtendedGCD[29, 22]

(* Out[100]= {1, {-3, 4}}

Out[101]= {1, {-3, 4}} *)
```

Mod 7 does not quite work because there is a smaller fractional equivalent: -1/3.

```
ExtendedGCD[7, 2]

(* Out[102]= {1, {1, -3}} *)
```

Clearly the multipliers could have been {-1,4} but that slightly violates the extended GCD guarantee on multiplier sizes in the case of two input, that neither exceeds half the size of the other value. (`ExtendedGCD` is not documented with such a guarantee, but the methods from the literature all provide this.) So my comment that only the prime 7 is required was slightly off.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!